# How to apply condition in ngFor in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to loop the user list with condition

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users" *ngIf="user.age>25"> {{user.name}} </li>
```

i know this is wrong. but,i want to use come like this. is there any possible way to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`ng-container`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives)** as follows

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users" >
   <li *ngIf="user.age>25">
      {{user.name}}
   </li> 
</ng-container>
```

Comment: it working well, but id creating unwanted dom like   <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->   it is not a problem but is there any way to stop that also?

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply more than one structural directive to the same element.
Just use ng-container:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
<li  *ngIf="user.age>25"> {{user.name}} </li>
<ng-container>
```

ng-container is

> a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.